# facing issues while installing Golang

Tags: go

I am facing some issues while installing go lang, have used below approach to install it.

sudo apt update

$ sudo curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

$ sudo tar -xvf go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

$ sudo mv go /usr/local

everything went fine till the above step.

But when I am giving below command, I am getting a message

$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> ~/.profile

**Message: bash: export: '/usr/local/go/bin': not a valid identifier**

$ source ~/.profile

Comment: these instructions work https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me the same error message which I mentioned in my question when I am doing **source ~/.profile**

Comment: Try copying and pasting the text instead of typing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
git clone https://github.com/udhos/update-golang
cd update-golang
sudo ./update-golang.sh
```

Full details: https://github.com/udhos/update-golang